# How to change Android Studio variable auto-naming scheme?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I create a variable for a class, the variable auto-suggested to me is the class name itself (Android Studio IDE)

```
Context context; //context variable suggested
```

I use auto suggestions heavily and would like to change the default suggestion to standard Android convention like this

```
Context mContext;
```

I tried looking up in templates preferences but could not figure a way out...

Comment: Which version Android Studio are you using? It matters, because older versions were forks of Eclipse, while newer versions are build on IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I'm using version 3.0 of Android studio along with Android Studio beta, which I believe is 3.1.0...